# Efficiently store array of up to 2048 characters?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, memory-management

Getting input from another source; which populates a string of up to 2048 characters.

What is the most efficient way of populating and comparing this string? - I want to be able to easily append to the string also.

Here are three attempts of mine:

#### C-style version

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main(void) {
    char foo[2048];
    foo[0]='a', foo[1]='b', foo[2]='c', foo[3]='\0';  // E.g.: taken from u-input
    puts(strcmp(foo, "bar")? "false": "true");
}
```

#### C++-style version 0

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string foo;
    foo.reserve(2048);
    foo += "abc";  // E.g.: taken from user-input
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (foo=="bar");
}
```

#### C++-style version 1

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string foo;
    foo += "abc";  // E.g.: taken from user-input
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (foo=="bar");
}
```

Comment: Do you understand how these two are different?

Comment: They use different data structures and different ways of streaming output. IIRC `std::string` does have a `const char*` internally somewhere.

Comment: one of them can be `return`ed in O(1).  `std::string` stores its data in the free store: an array does it in automatic storage.  Plus, the `string` is all gussied up, and handles too-large input without undefined behaviour...

Comment: `#include <cstdio>` is not really C-style.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: Yes it is; it's just not C. It's C-style C++. Yakk: So you are saying that my second C++ version is what I should be using?

Comment: Use the one that's easier, so one of the C++ versions, seeing that you already got an bug in your C version. **Hint** `strcmp` returns 0 if the strings are equal.

Comment: If you're using C++, then use C++. Don't try to "optimize" your code thinking using C style syntax will be better.

Comment: What do you mean by "most efficient"?

Comment: The people who wrote your C++ (or C) library presumably know much more than you on how to do things efficiently. Besides, worrying about such details *before having detailed measurements showing it is relevat for performance* is firmly in the [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) camp.

Comment: the first version should be `char foo[2049]` or it'll cause undefined behavior when the input string is 2048 characters long. Using std::string you won't face that problem

Comment: Which of the last 2 C++ versions are "better" depends on how many characters your string have in average and how do you define "efficient"

Answer (score 1):

What is most efficient depends on what you optimize for.
Some common criteria:

1. Program Speed
2. Program Size
3. Working Set Size
4. Code Size
5. Programmer Time
6. Safety

Undoubted King for 1 and 2, in your example probably also 3, is C style.
For 4 and 5, C++ style 1.
Point 6 is probably with C++-style.

Still, the proper mix of emphasizing these goal is called for, which imho favors C++ option 0.

Comment: That is up to debate. Well-written C++ can definitely be as fast/small/cache friendly as well-written C. And a quick computation shows that programmer time spent "optimizing" (and later maintaining the resulting mess) is overwhelmingly more expensive than any spent computer time, except in *very* particular circumstances. Depending on the application, (6) might very well be the overriding concern.

Comment: @vonbrand: Well, in this case it won't, as the C-style code does not even use dynamic memory. It is just about as fully optimized as can be, while the C++ code uses std::string (and dynamic allocation). I certainly concur that 5 and 6 should be very much the main concern most of the time. Though not too much, or we would use a scripting language instead.

Comment: The beauty (curse?) of C++ is that you *can* write essentially C code if required...

Comment: @vonbrand: As the OP demonstrated ;-)